# change fps while-loops exporting ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, export, frame-rate

I am new to FFMPEG. I am trying to export still images from a video file. I did it correctly.

Now i want to change average frame rate. That is if my video is 24fps and i want to export still images with 30fps. Now instead of 24 frames I need 30 frames.

Cany you please help me what to do.

Thanks in advance
wizards

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-r` command line option to FFmpeg to specify the output frame rate e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 30 output.mp4
```

See the [FFmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC6) here.